# How to improve data synchronization using Unity an multicast UDP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp, multicastsocket

I'm teaching myself some simple networking using Unity and Sockets and I'm running into problems synchronizing data between a client and server. I'm aware that there are other options using Unity Networking but, before I move on, I want to understand better how to improve my code using the System libraries.

In this example I'm simply trying to stream my mouse position over a multicast UDP socket. I'm encoding a string into a byte array and sending that array once per frame. I'm aware that sending these values as a string is un-optimal but, unless that is likely the bottleneck, I'm assuming It's ok come back to optimize that later.

Im my setup server is sending values at 60 fps, and the client is reading at the same rate. The problem I'm having is that when the client receives values it typically receives many at once. If I log the values I received with a `-----` between each frame I typically get output like this:

```
------
------
------
------
------
------
------
119,396
91,396
45,391
18,379
-8,362
-35,342
-59,314
------
------
------
------
------
------
------
```

I would expect unsynchronized update cycles to lead to receiving two values per frame, but I'm not sure what might be accounting for the larger discrepancy.

Here's the Server code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    Socket _socket;

    void OnEnable ()
    {
        var ip = IPAddress.Parse ("224.5.6.7");
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, 4567);

        _socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        _socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption (ip));
        _socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);
        _socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
    }

    void OnDisable ()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.Close();
            _socket = null;
        }
    }

    public void Send (string message)
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (message);
        _socket.Send (byteArray);
    }
}
```

And the client:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    Socket _socket;
    byte[] _byteBuffer = new byte[16];

    public delegate void MessageRecievedEvent (string message);
    public MessageRecievedEvent messageWasRecieved = delegate {};
    

    void OnEnable ()
    {
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4567);
        var ip = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");

        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        _socket.Bind (ipEndPoint);
        _socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip,IPAddress.Any));
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        while (_socket.Available > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _byteBuffer.Length; i++) _byteBuffer[i] = 0;
            _socket.Receive (_byteBuffer);
            messageWasRecieved (Encoding.ASCII.GetString (_byteBuffer));
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody could shed light on what I can do to improve synchronization that would be a great help.

Comment: You know that `_socket.Receive (_byteBuffer);` is a **blocking call** you do not want in your main thread. Rather do the entire receive and string conversion process in a background thread and only dispatch the received messages back into the main thread. Also the sender should probably just convert and send his stuff in a thread or task. There still will be no real guarantee that you will catch exactly one package per frame .. in general you might anyway only want to handle the very last received package per frame and drop the previous ones

Comment: @derHugo Absolutely - I will certainly move this to its own thread. That said, right now every frame is completing fast enough that it doesn't look as if blocking is contributing this particular issue.

Comment: Absolutely no networking expert thought but maybe anyone I the network is waiting until a package gets big enough to send and then splits them again into the actual messages? Did you try rather using `UdpClient` and let it handle the underlying sockets?

Comment: @derHugo Great observation. I tried a simple hack where I padded the string I was sending with white spaces and indeed the packets were distributed more evenly. I'll look into `UDPClient` but also I'll see if I can find an option to send smaller packets to get this version working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network I/O is subject to a large number of external influences, and TCP/IP as a protocol has few requirements. Certainly none that would provide a guarantee of the behavior you seem to want.

Unfortunately, without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's not possible to verify that your server is in fact sending data at the interval you claim. It's entirely possible you have a bug that's causing this behavior.

But if we assume that the code itself is perfect, there are still no guarantees when using UDP that datagrams won't be batched up at some point along the way, such that a large number appear in the network buffer all at once. I would expect this to happen with higher frequency when the datagrams are sent through multiple network nodes (e.g. a switch and especially over the Internet), but it could just as easily happen when the server and client are both on the same computer.

Ironically, one option that *might* force the datagrams to be spread out more is to pad each datagram with extra bytes. The exact number of bytes required would depend on the exact network route; to do this "perfectly" might require writing some calibration logic that tries different padding amounts until the code sees datagrams arriving at the intervals it expects.

But that would significantly increase the complexity of your network I/O code, and yet still would not *guarantee* the behavior you'd like. And it has some obvious negative side-effects, including the extra overhead on the network (something people using metered network connections certainly won't appreciate), as well as increasing the likelihood of a UDP datagram being dropped altogether.

It's not clear from your question whether your project actually requires multicast UDP, or if that's just something in your code because that's what some tutorial or other example you're following was using. If multicast is not actually a requirement, another thing you definitely should try is to use direct UDP without multicasting.

FWIW: I would not implement this the way you have. Instead, I would use asynchronous receive operations, so that my client receives datagrams the instant they are available, rather than only checking periodically each frame of rendering. I would also include a sequence number in the datagram, and discard (ignore) any datagrams that arrive out of sequence (i.e. where the sequence number isn't strictly greater than the most recent sequence number already received). This approach will improve (perhaps only slightly) responsiveness, but also will handle situations where the datagrams arrive out of order, or are duplicated (two of the three main delivery issues one will experience with UDP…the third being, of course, failure of delivery).

Comment: Thank-you for the comprehensive answer. Though it's most likely not the most efficient solution, padding the data did improve the issue problem I was experiencing in this situation